# assembly language 8051 syntax error

Tags: assembly, 8051

i am new to assembly language.
i want to run that code for 8051 controller,but its not working properly.
it gives syntax error.
kindly help me

```
org
mov a,#38h
acall comnwrt
mov delay
acall a,30eh
acall comnwrt
mov delay
acall a,#01
acall comnwrt
mov delay
acall #06h
acall comnwrt
mov delay
acall a,#84h
acall delay
mov a,#'N'
acall datawrt
sjmp again
mov p1,a
clr p2,0
clr p2.1
setb p2.2
clr p2.2
ret e
mov p1.a
setb p2.0
clr p2.0
mov r3,#50
mov r4,#255
djnz r4,here
djnz r3,here
end
```

Comment: Does it tell you where the syntax error is?

Comment: on almost every line of code

Comment: What toolchain are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Many assemblers require that the instructions be indented (either with spaces or  tab character). The left column is reserved for labels and possibly assembler directives.